# DomPDF setting landscape orientation

Tags: codeigniter, dompdf

I am having trouble setting DOMPDF to use landscape orientation. Could anyone shed some light on my problem in the code below?

```
function delivary_voucher($arr = null, $orientation = 'landscape') {

        $this->load->library('dompdf_gen');
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->load->model('Emailtemplatemodel');
```

Comment: You'll need to clarify the issue. At what point in the process are you setting the document orientation? What library are you using? [This one](https://github.com/iamfiscus/Codeigniter-DOMPDF)? The [test controller](https://github.com/iamfiscus/Codeigniter-DOMPDF/blob/master/controllers/dompdf_test.php) shows dompdf injected into the current class, so your next statement might be: `$this->dompdf->set_paper('letter', $orientation);`

Answer (score 3):

I am having the same problem. After searching a lot I have finally understood how to solve the issue. I am answering this just after my coding. Hope it could help you and also for a reference of **SO**.

Here is how I solve the problem:

I am using `dompdf` as a helper, so I put the folder `dompdf` into `system>helpers` folder.
Then I have created a helper file named `dompdf_helper.php` into the same folder containing the following code:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

function get_pdf($html, $paper_size='a4', $orientation='portrait', $filename='', $stream=TRUE) 
{
    require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);

    // THE FOLLOWING LINE OF CODE IS YOUR CONCERN
    $dompdf->set_paper($paper_size, $orientation);

    $dompdf->render();

    // added by Siddiqui Noor on 29 Nov, 15
    if( !empty($filename) && $stream ) {
         $dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf"); // to Download PDF
    } else if ($stream) {            
        $dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf",array('Attachment'=>0));// to open in a window
    } else {
        return $dompdf->output();
    }
}
?>
```

My `system` folder looks like the [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RcaW.jpg)

Finally I call the `get_pdf` function in my controller like:

```
$data = 'Your result set goes here';
$this->load->helper(array('dompdf', 'file'));
$html = $this->load->view($view, $data, true);
get_pdf($html,'a4', 'landscape');
```

Happy coding as code is poetry :)